# sidebar is not collapsing when removing code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django, django-templates

I have the following html that I'm customizing from the sb-admin template -

`http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/`

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

{% load static %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>{% block title %}Company Dashboard{% endblock %}</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="{% static "css/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{% static "css/sb-admin-2.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="{% static "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="/dashboard/">{{ user.customer.company }} Dashboard</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->

            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                <a>Production Date {% now "jS F Y H:i" %} EST</a>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>Read All Messages</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-messages -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-tasks">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 1</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">40% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 2</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">20% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 3</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">60% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 4</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">80% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">80% Complete (danger)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>See All Tasks</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-tasks -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> New Comment
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> 3 New Followers
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Message Sent
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> New Task
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Server Rebooted
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                        <li><a href={% url 'dashboard_profile' %}><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href={% url 'dashboard_settings' %}><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href={% url 'index' %}><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
            </ul>
            <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->
            <!-- sidebar left -->
            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                        <li class="sidebar-search">
                            <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /input-group -->
                        </li>
                        {% if not user.admin %}
                        <li>
                            <a href={% url 'dashboard_admin' %}><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i> Admin</a>
                        </li>
                        {% endif %}
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-th-list fa-fw"></i> Files<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="files/index.html">Vendors</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href={% url 'request' %}> Request</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Analytics<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="files/index.html">Reports</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="files/index.html">Custom</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw"></i> Documentation<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href={% url 'faq' %}> FAQ</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href={% url 'faq' %}> API</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
        </nav>
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Welcome {{ user.first_name }} </h1>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}

            <!-- /.row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">


                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div id="morris-area-chart"></div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4">

                                </div>
                                <!-- /.col-lg-4 (nested) -->
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    <div id="morris-bar-chart"></div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.col-lg-8 (nested) -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.row -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">

                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-8 -->

                <div class="col-lg-4">

                    <div class="panel panel-default">

                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div id="morris-donut-chart"></div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>


                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="{% static "js/jquery.js" %}"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static "js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static "js/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js" %}"></script>

    <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static "js/plugins/morris/raphael.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/plugins/morris/morris-data.js" %}"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static "js/sb-admin-2.js" %}"></script>

</body>

</html>

{% else %}

This page is restricted!

{% endif %}
```

As soon as I remove the following line -

```
<div id="morris-donut-chart"></div>
```

The collapse on the sidebar stops working.  I'm at a loss as to what in this row is forcing the sidebar javascript to stop loading.

Comment: check your browser console for the error... and also post error console.

Comment: Thanks!  I ran the console and found the issue.  I had to delete the related js scripts from the end of my code - 
`    <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static "js/plugins/morris/raphael.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/plugins/morris/morris-data.js" %}"></script>`